# Unable to delete data from a Cassandra CF

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

So I have a CF whose Schema looks something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE "emp" (
id text,
column1 text,
column2 text,
PRIMARY KEY (id, column1, column2)
)
```

I have an entry which looks like this and I want to delete it :

```
20aff8144049 | name | someValue
```

So i tried this command :

```
Delete column2 from emp where id='20aff8144049';
```

It failed with below error:

no viable alternative at input '20aff8144049' (...column2 from emp where id=["20aff8144049]...)

Can someone help with where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**You can't delete or set null to primary key column**

You have to delete the entire row.

Answer (score 3):

You only can delete an entry using a valid value for your primary key. You defined your primary key to include (id, column1, column2) which means that you have to put all the corresponding values in your where clause.

However, I assume you wanted to be able to delete by id only. Therefore, I'd suggest you re-define your column family like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "emp" (
    id text,
    column1 text,
    column2 text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id), column1, column2)
)
```

where id is your partition key and column1 and column2 are your clustering columns.

Comment: Could you share the syntax?

Comment: For the differentiation between partition and clustering columns? It's already there: PRIMARY KEY ((id), column1, column2). You have to put the partition key columns in additional brackets.

Comment: No, for the delete query.

Comment: try: delete from "test" where id = '20aff8144049';

Comment: I just realized that I missed that you do not want to delete the entire record. Sorry for that. So, then it's not actually a delete what you want to do but an update/upsert. So, if you want to use PRIMARY KEY ((id), column1, column2) that you need to INSERT INTO "test" (id, column1, column2) VALUES ('20aff8144049', 'name', null); if column1 and column2 do not need to be a primary key, then you can do INSERT INTO "test" (id, column2) VALUES ('20aff8144049',  null);

Comment: I want to delete the entire row....when I said "entry" I actually meant the entire row.. my bad.

Comment: OK got it!! I was using double quotes, once I used single quotes...error went away. Woof!